# Retrieving data while rendering form in django

Tags: django

I have a form with some fields. I want to display all fields in form except two. However one field data needs to be displayed.
I am able to get the form but not able to retrieve the data from DB to display.

Model.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(
                    ('service','service'),
                    ('product','product'),
    )
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    company_address=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Company_telephone=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    company_email=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    company_website=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    VAT=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    Service_Tax=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    company_PAN=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    company_bankdetails=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    invoice_type=models.CharField(max_length=250,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='service')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'self.user.company_name'
```

forms.py

```
class companyeditform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Company
        exclude = ('user','company_name',)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def companyadd(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        company_form=companyeditform(instance=request.user.company,data=request.POST)
        if company_form.is_valid():
            new_form=company_form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.save()
            return render(request,'account/dashboard.html',{'section':'addcompany'})
    else:
        company_form=companyeditform(instance=request.user.company)
    company_details=Company.objects.get(user=request.user.company)
    return render(request,'account/company.html',{'company_form':company_form})
```

When form is displayed everything works as planned. However not getting company_name.
Using this query to get company name.

```
company_details=Company.objects.get(user=request.user.company)
```

Django gives following error:

```
Cannot query "self.user.company_name": Must be "User" instance.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this query `company_details=Company.objects.get(user=request.user.company)` you are trying to get the company of a particular user. But in the statement, you are comparing `user=request.user.company`, both are two different types (User is the authuser model and request.user.company is the Company model). You cannot do this in the query.

`company_details=Company.objects.get(user=request.user)` This statement will solve the issue. And also you can do 
`company_details=request.user.company` because the association is OneToOne.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting that error, is because you are trying to fetch a Company by filtering it out the company that matches the current user, but you are passing in the actual company object:

```
company_details=Company.objects.get(user=request.user.company)
#                                                     ^^^^^^^
```

You can fix the line, by doing this:

```
company_details=Company.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

But you already have the correct object, in `request.user.company`, you don't need to fetch it again, simply:

```
company_details = request.user.company
print(company_details.company_name)
```

In fact, since you are using the `render` shortcut, you don't even need to do this step, as the request object will be available in your template, so all you need to do really is:

```
Company: {{ request.user.company.company_name }}
```

Finally, you should always redirect after a POST request (see [this article on wikipedia for the details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)).

Answer (score 1):

`request.user` might be a class like `AnonymousUser`. Do some extra processing to ensure that `request.user` is the type provided by `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`.

Comment: request.user won't be AnonymousUser, because the login_required decorator ensures that the current user is a valid user and authenticated.